# get one of 2 dimensional array android

Tags: java, android

I'm new in Android. I have `story.xml` in string folder which contains:

```
<string-array name="story">
    <item>
        <name>st2</name>
        <id>1</id>
    </item>
    <item>
        <name>st1</name>
        <id>2</id>
    </item>
</string-array>
```

I use this code to get this array and show in `ListView` :

```
String[]  sto_li = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.story);
ArrayAdapter<String> storylist;
        storylist = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, sto_li);

list.setAdapter(storylist);
```

In list view show like this:

```
st21
.............
st12
```

But I only want to show:

```
st2
.........
st1
```

What is the best way to get the second output on `ListView`?

Comment: Android is "just" java. This isn't really Android-specific.

Comment: @MarcB Except that `ArrayAdapter` is not part of the Java API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get the identifier for the name like so: `int resId = getResources().getIdentifier("story", "name", getPackageName());`

Then do:
`String[] sto_li = getResources().getStringarray(resId);`

Give that a try.

[Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)